# Why does my button look different when I click it?

Tags: html, css

I've created a submit button but every time I click it, it the border goes away and the corners become hazy. but then when you click outside the submit button, the look returns to normal. I'm not exactly sure why. I just want it so that my button looks the same all the way through the click. Here's my code:

```
<input class="Submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>

.Submit {
    background-color:#2b6ba1;
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    height:30px;
    width:80px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #1b4898;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 2px black;
}

.Submit:hover {
    background-color:#2276bd;
}

.Submit:active {
    background-color:#185589;
    top:1px;
}
```

And here's the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/z1ounhkm/

If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated, thank you

Comment: looks fine in safari, not so nice in chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add this on your css:

```
.Submit:focus {outline:0;}
```

here the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z1ounhkm/6/

Comment: didn't even know there was an outline attribute +1

Answer (score 2):

It is because in chrome when you focus on button then by default it will take

```
:focus {
  outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

So, just make it 0 will solved your issue.

```
    .Submit:focus{
    outline:0;
}
```